# How can I format a string?

Tags: c#, string, string-formatting, stringbuilder

My string looks like 0145655789, I want to change its format to 0145.655.789

This is the code I tried:

enterpriseCode and aNum are both StringBuilder objects

```
enterpriseCode.Append(String.Format("{0:####.###.###}", aNum.ToString()).Replace(";", ""));
```

enterpriseCode still contains 0145655789 instead of 0145.655.789

Comment: so should I convert aNum to integer?

Comment: Yes, or not convert it to a string in the first place (more efficient), or add the formatting while you are building it.

Comment: Can I check: the `.` in the above - is that a "thousands separator" in your particular locale? Or is that just an opaque meaningless token? If it is thousands, then in the format string you need to use `,`; `,` means "the current culture's thousand separator"; `.` means "the current culture's decimal separator". If it is just a token, you will need to escape it.

Comment: @Marc, if using the thousand separator, the result is `0.145.655.789` for me, which isn't what they are after. That's the reason why I hardcoded the point in the format string in my answer.

Comment: @Joey indeed, if the `.` is just a token (unrelated to thousands / decimals), then your `'.'` is perfect

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's because the format string you gave is for numerical arguments, not strings. It will simply be ignored if the argument is a string.

You can pass the argument as a number instead, and use something like

```
{0:0000'.'000'.'000}
```

as the format string. Quick PowerShell test:

```
PS> "{0:0000'.'000'.'000}" -f 145655789
0145.655.789
```

Answer (score 2):

This will work

```
string formatted = enterpriseCode.Insert(4, ".").Insert(8, ".");
```